# I have to combine php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, database

I have a table (SQL Server 2008) that have field1 and field2. if the check box `myCheckBox` is checked, then the value for `<label id="priceLabel" />` will use the value in field1 and if it's not checked, the label will use the value from field2.

I don't understand AJAX very well so I'm thinking that I should use javascript in changing the label's value without having to reset all the other components' values. I read that we shouldn't use javascript to connect to database but I don't know of any other way..

can someone tell me what to do in this situation?

Comment: the title should've been "to combine"..

Comment: Using Ajax means using JS or jQuery. "can someone tell me what to do in this situation?" is not clear.

Comment: And using jQuery implicitly means using JS.

Comment: @GolezTrol very true!

Comment: But you should solve one problem at the time. Your primary concern seems to be to gain an understanding of Ajax. You don't need a database for that, so leave SQL server out of the equasion.

Comment: The guidance to not access your db from JS does not imply not to use AJAX. Make a call from AJAX to a script on a web server and have that script access the database. The script can be written in PHP, Python, a .NET language, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough diagram of how this works:

```
User's Workstation     |              Your Server(s)
                       |
+-------------+        |   +-------------+     +-------------+
|   Browser   |        |   |     PHP     |     |             |
+-------------+        |   +-------------+     |      DB     |
| JavaScript  |<---------->| PHP Code    |<--->|             |
|    code     |  ajax  |   | talks to DB |     |             |
+-------------+        |   +-------------+     +-------------+
```

So your JavaScript code uses ajax to talk to your PHP code. Your PHP code talks to your DB. JavaScript on the browser should never be used to talk directly to your DB, even if you set up the infrastructure, because of course it's running on the end user's browser and so it has to have limited permissions. You have to protect your DB from the outside world.

That's what your PHP code does: It's both a gatekeeper and a data transformer. It gets the data from the DB, transforms it into a format that will be useful on the client (usually HTML, text, JSON, or XML), and passes that on to the JavaScript code in the browser, which then uses that HTML, text, JSON, or XML to show something to the user or similar.

Looking at those in (slightly) more detail:

1. The JavaScript Ajax Request

   Using JavaScript to send an ajax request is quite easy, particularly if you use a decent library to work around some browser inconsistencies. Fundamentally, it looks like this:

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
   xhr.open("GET", "your_php_file.php");
   xhr.send();
   function handleReadyStateChange() {
       if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 0 || (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300))) {
           // ===> This is where we can use the resulting information <===
       }
   }
   ```

   Let's look at that in more detail:

   ```
   // Create the request object
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   // Set up a callback for when things happen
   xhr.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;

   // Open the request
   xhr.open("GET", "your_php_file.php");
   //       ^      ^----------------------- a normal URL like any other
   //       |------------------------------ the kind of request (GET, POST, ...)

   // Send it (if this were a POST, you'd include data as an
   // argument to `sent`, typically as a URI-encoded string
   xhr.send();

   // IMPORTANT: As of this point in the code, the request has been
   // *sent*, but it has not yet *completed*. By default, ajax is
   // *asynchronous*.

   // Our callback for ready state changes
   function handleReadyStateChange() {
       // Is the request complete?
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // 4 = complete
           // Yes, did it succeed? (`status` is a standard HTTP status code
           // except that *some* browsers sometimes use 0 if the response came
           // from cache)
           if (xhr.status === 0 || (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)) {
               // If the Content-Type header of the HTTP response was for XML,
               // the XML document is on `xhr.responseXML`.
               // Otherwise, the HTML, text, or JSON is on `xhr.responseText`

               // ===> This is where we can use the resulting information <===
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The PHP Code

   The ajax request looks like any other page request to the PHP code. (It's possible to tell them apart if you need to, but it's rare that you need to). So your PHP code is just like any other PHP code you write. It will probably have different output, though. You're used to PHP "pages" rendering a complete HTML page for the browser. When responding to an ajax request, though, you're not sending back a full page, you're sending back information the code on the page will use.

   Here's one example of what the PHP might look like, but again, as this is just like the other PHP you write, it can be *anything*:

   ```
   <?php
       // In our case, we'll return plain text from our example, so
       // mark the response accordingly
       header("Content-Type", "text/plain");

       // We might use $_GET or $_POST variables here, to get
       // information from the request

       // Once we've authenticated that the request comes from
       // an authorised user, we might connect to the database
       // and retrieve some information here

       // Output our response
       echo("Hi there");
   ?>
   ```

   There we're returning plain text. Again, you can return lots of things. JSON is popular for when you're returning data to the page. On the PHP side, you'd build up the data in a memory structure (arrays and such) and then convert it to a string to use with `echo` via  `json_encode`. On the JavaScript side, you'd parse that JSON with `JSON.parse` on modern browsers. (For older browsers, you'll have to add a JSON parser to your page, which is another reason to use a good library like jQuery, which provides one for you.)

Here's a complete example of the HTML and JavaScript side: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iparox/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iparox/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Ajax Example</title>
  <style>
    #theSpan {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Click Me">
  <p>Here is the span we'll fill in: <span id="theSpan"></span></p>
  <script>
    (function() {
        // Hook up our button click handler
        document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
            // Do our ajax request

            // Create the request object
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Set up a callback for when things happen
            xhr.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;

            // Open the request
            xhr.open("GET", "/uvanep/1");
            //       ^      ^----------------------- a normal URL like any other
            //       |------------------------------ the kind of request (GET, POST, ...)

            // Send it (if this were a POST, you'd include data as an
            // argument to `sent`, typically as a URI-encoded string
            xhr.send();

            // IMPORTANT: As of this point in the code, the request has been
            // *sent*, but it has not yet *completed*. By default, ajax is
            // *asynchronous*.

            // Our callback for ready state changes
            function handleReadyStateChange() {
                // Is the request complete?
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // 4 = complete
                    // Yes, did it succeed? (`status` is a standard HTTP status code
                    // except that *some* browsers sometimes use 0 if the response came
                    // from cache)
                    if (xhr.status === 0 || (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)) {
                        // If the Content-Type header of the HTTP response was for XML,
                        // the XML document is on `xhr.responseXML`.
                        // Otherwise, the HTML, text, or JSON is on `xhr.responseText`

                        // ===> This is where we can use the resulting information <===
                        // In this case, let's put it in our span:
                        document.getElementById("theSpan").appendChild(
                          document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In that case, the page we're calling just returns the text `"Hi there"`.

Comment: Nice diagram. It may be good to add, that an Ajax request is (almost) the same as a normal request regarding to PHP. The only difference is that it's fired by Javascript and handled by Javascript, instead of showing a new page in the browser. (And of course there's this extra header in case PHP wants to know if it was Ajax or not.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don not need something too crazy ...
you can simple pre-load the 2 fields, make there values accessible in the view, and switch the value with JavaScript:

```
<?php
  $label1 = 'field1_value'; //get this value from the DB
  $label2 = 'field2_value'; 
?>

<html>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" onclick="changeValue();" />
    <label id="priceLabel" ><?php echo $label1; ?><label>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeValue(){
           var check = document.getElementById('myCheckBox');
           var label = document.getElementById('priceLabel');

           if(check.checked){
               label.innerHTML = "<?php echo $label2; ?>";
           }else{
               label.innerHTML = "<?php echo $label2; ?>";
           }
        }
    </script>

<html>
```

It may be done much nicer, just showing the concept here.